# Django: converting the "date_joined" field on the AbstractUser class to only month and year precision

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, datetime-format

I have a Django model with a `User` class that inherits from `AbstractUser`.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

In the Django Admin screen, I see that the `date_joined` field has month, day, year, and time precision.

I also have a Django template with the following code:

```
{% block header%}
    <h2>{{ profile.username }}</h2>
    <h3>{{ profile.date_joined }}</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

Not surprisingly, this renders as follows:

**Foo Bar**

**July 4, 2021, 6:38 p.m.**

What I'd like is for it to render as **only the month and date**, as follows:

**Foo Bar**

**July 2021**

Is is possible to convert the `date_joined` field on the `User` class to month and year only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can format the timestamp with the [**`|date`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

```
<h3>{{ profile.date_joined|date:"F Y" }}</h3>
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I didn't realize it was possible to format inside the template!